# Session data not persisting

Tags: session, model-view-controller, redis, servicestack

Session data is not persisting between requests. This only seems to happen when using session data from a 'non-default' area from within an MVC application.

The application is using a Redis backed session state server and a Service Stack authentication implementation.

Session data added within the default area seems to persist, even after authentication (which redirects users into a new area of the site). Also, two user cookies are being set, these are ss:id and ss:pid.

Thanks

Comment: You've not provided anywhere near enough info for anyone to have any chance at identifying what the issue is or being able to reproduce it, e.g. code showing what's not working, where you're saving the Session, proof that the session isn't being saved, etc.

Comment: The service stack authentication was maybe a little misleading as the authentication is remote. 

As I mentioned, this project is using a Custom Redis Session State Provider. The code to store the information is simply:

HttpContext.Current.Session["searchModel"]

I can see that the key is in the session before the end of the Action. Then I am using a RedirectToAction and a breakpoint in the next action and inspection of the Session data shows that the key and item has not persisted.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session is ASP.NET's Session, it has nothing to do with ServiceStack Sessions which is a completely decoupled separate implementation.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I did mention that it is a Redis Session State Server and I only mentioned the Service Stack authentication in connection with the cookies being set. I didnt want to imply that forms authentication was happening

Answer (score 0):

If the session is not being saved I'm assuming you're not saving the Session. Refer to the Session docs on how to [Save a Session both inside and outside of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#saving-in-service).

Answer (score 0):

Just for anybody else experiencing this same issue, the configuration for the custom redis session state provider included a 'throwOnError' property which was set to false. At an earlier point in the code base it turns out a non-serialisable class was being added to session data and causing this problem but it was not highlighted due to the throwOnError=false.